How to deploy a private Chrome extension through Google Admin Console?
How to deploy a private Chrome extension through Google Admin Console?
I have developed a Chrome extension for internal use in my organization. I've successfully tested it using the "Load unpacked" option in developer mode.
Now I'm trying to deploy it through Google Admin Console (Google Workspace) for a specific Organizational Unit (OU), but I'm facing some challenges.
What I've tried:

In Google Admin Console:

Went to Devices > Chrome > Apps and Extensions
Selected my target OU
Clicked "+" to add new extension
Selected "Add custom app or extension by ID"


When trying to add the extension:

It asks for the Extension ID (which I have)
But then only gives me two options:

"From custom URL"
"From the Chrome Web Store"





My questions:

What's the proper way to deploy a private extension that's not in the Chrome Web Store?
If I need to use a "custom URL", where should I host the .crx file?
Are there any enterprise-specific requirements or configurations I need to consider?

Environment:

Chrome Version: 129.0.6668.103

Any guidance on the correct deployment process would be greatly appreciated.


Chrome Version: 129.0.6668.103

If chromium is ok for you - you can just add 1 commit and distribute your own extension by your own site. Here's the commit - https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/4295004b1d0fb511ff5871bf264fe43a8e4693a7 works for 129.0.6668.101
More details:

https://www.reddit.com/r/UltimatumBrowser/comments/1hih78e/ultimatum_debut/
https://github.com/gonzazoid/chromium

